# How many times does the same character occur twice in a row

Tags: grep, regular-expression

My task is using grep to find how many times the same character occurs twice in a row.
I was thinking about something like this but it isn`t working

```
grep '[a-zA-z]{2}' *.txt | wc
```

How can achieve such a task with grep?

Comment: In `aaa`, does `a` appear twice in a row once (`[aa]a`, `aa[a?]`) or twice (`[aa]a`, `a[aa]`)?

Comment: Think back references. Check the man page for the regular expression syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In an input file like:

```
foo

baaar
```

I count 4 occurrences of a character being repeated: `oo`, `<NL><NL>`, `aa` and `aa`.

To count the repeating characters within a line, you could use `perl`-style regular expression like `(.)(?=\1)`. For repeating newline, you can count the empty lines except if it's the first line.

You could get close with GNU `grep`

```
grep -Po '^$|(.)(?=\1)' | wc -l
```

But that would count the first empty line, so you could remove it first or add a `xx` on empty lines except the first one:

```
sed '1!s/^$/xx/' | grep -Po '(.)(?=\1)' | wc -l
```